# Compare 2 lists, based on index from 2 other lists, and save index in new list with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, indexing, comparison, list-comprehension

So what I am trying to do is:

1) Find where list1[y] == list2[x]

2) Determine if list3[y] < (0.4 list4[x])

3) If so, store the index y in a new list of indexes

This loop works, however it takes almost a full minute to run with my data set.  I want to know if I can do this with list comprehension.

Thanks in advance for anybody's help.

```
    for y in range(len(list1)):
        for x in range(len(list2)):
            if list1[y] == list2[x]:
                if list3[y] < (0.4 * list4[x]):
                    list5.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will provide a significant performance increase, but try this:

```
list5 = [y for y, val1 in enumerate(list1) for x, val2 in enumerate(list2) if val1 == val2 and list3[y] < (0.4 * list4[x])]
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this takes it down to about 10 seconds.  This is perfect, thank you very much.

Comment: @GitGud No problem, glad to have helped! If this answer helped you, make sure to mark it as accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers